# Existe alguma maneira de importa uma dependência para dentro de um objeto? NODE.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Electron junto com Node.js, e não consigo importar uma dependência dentro de um objeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível fazer isso, importar uma dependência para dentro de um objeto?

```
const conexao = {    

    **//Acredito que o problema está aqui.**
    msql = require('mysql'),

    connection = msql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password : 'root',
        database: 'bd_barbearia'
    }),

    criarConexao: function(){
        connection.connect();
    },

    fecharConexao: function(){
        connection.end();
    },

    verificarUsuario: function(nome,senha){
        connect.query("call verificarCliente('"+this.nome+"','"+this.senha+"')", function(error,results){
            if(error) throw error;
            lista = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results[0]));
            resposta = String(lista[0].alert);

            return resposta;
        });
    }
};

module.exports = conexao;
```

Comment: Por que você simplesmente não coloca a importação do MySQL fora do objeto? Assim você não precisará com os diversos problemas que o `this` do JS traz...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro realmente está na linha que você colocou o comentário. Não por causa do `require`, mas sim por causa do `=` onde o correto seria utilizar `:`.

Para criar um objeto no javascript você deve seguir [algumas regras](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Aprender/JavaScript/Objetos/B%C3%A1sico):

> Cada par nome/valor deve ser separado por uma vírgula e o nome e
>   valor, em cada caso, separados por dois pontos. A sintaxe sempre segue
>   esse padrão:

```js
var nomeDoObjeto = {
  nomeMembro1: valorMembro1,
  nomeMembro2: valorMembro2,
  nomeMembro3: valorMembro3
};
```

Sendo assim, o correto no seu código seria:

```
// estamos deixando a importação "do lado de fora" do objeto para não termos problemas com referência do objeto.
const mysql = require('mysql');

// mesma coisa com com sua conexão.
const connection = msql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database: 'bd_barbearia'
})

const conexao = {

    **//Acredito que o problema está aqui.**
    msql: mysql, // mude o = por :

    connection: connection,

    criarConexao: function(){
        connection.connect();
    },

    fecharConexao: function(){
        connection.end();
    },

    verificarUsuario: function(nome,senha){
        connect.query("call verificarCliente('"+this.nome+"','"+this.senha+"')", function(error,results){
            if(error) throw error;
            lista = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results[0]));
            resposta = String(lista[0].alert);

            return resposta;
        });
    }
};

module.exports = conexao;
```